# How can I make the horizontal scroll buttons on a tab control larger?

Tags: winforms

I'm using a `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl`.  I'm using it for a touch screen interface, and when there are a lot of tabs in the `TabControl`, the scroll arrows on the right side of the top of the `TabControl` are too small to touch.  How can I resize them to make them larger?

edit: I have `Multiline` set to false, to enable more screen space for my application.  If I need to change this back to `true`, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiline would probably be the best bet here. Alternatively, you could make two buttons of your own, size them to the desired size and bind them to the following:

**Left (or down in pages):**

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != tabControl1.TabPages[0])
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex - 1];
}
```

**Right (or up):**

```
if(tabControl1.SelectedTab != tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1])
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedTab.TabIndex + 1];
}
```

I just utilized two buttons and I can page accordingly and control their style.